# MAMP crash "quit unexpectedly" when stopping Apache server?

Tags: macos, exception, crash, mamp

Whenever I stop the Apache server (or do this by quitting MAMP - which is otherwise running just fine; or restart Apache by changing PHP versions) I get a "quit unexpectedly" dialog.

Details: http://pastebin.com/raw/cd8pfuRx

Log: http://pastebin.com/raw/tuJnJvMv

My setup:

- MAMP 4.0.5
- macOS Sierra 10.12 (16A320)

So obviously an MAMP/Apache issue, but what?

Any ideas?

[image: quit unexpectedly]